# Circular Progress Button – different times for different buttons

Tags: javascript

I'm trying integrate [these awesome circular buttons](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/04/09/how-to-create-a-circular-progress-button/) with my form. Everything works but I have one problem: I wanna different status time for each button.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/uqgv0838/1/
I wanna that second button will have status a bit longer.

This piece of code is for status time:

```
UIProgressButton.prototype.options = {
// time in ms that the status (success or error will be displayed) - should be at least higher than the transition-duration value defined for the stroke-dashoffset transition of both checkmark and cross strokes 
statusTime : 1500
}
```

How can I set this time for each button individually?

It'd be great if each status also have different types. E.g. "success" will be forever but "error" only for several seconds.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **programming** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Programming questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is by making a small change to the `UIProgressButton.prototype.stop` function.

You need to make sure that you

1. do not get rid of the `statusClass` class
2. manually set the statusTime by editing `self.options.statusTime` to whatever value you want it to be.

Check the edit I made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uqgv0838/3/). Look at the function mentioned above.

I just changed (from the stop() function)

```
       setTimeout( function() {
           classie.remove( self.el, statusClass );
           statusEl.draw(0);
           self._enable();
       }, self.options.statusTime );
```

to include an if statement and updated statusTime

```
  if(status < 0){ // This indicates success so we do not want to remove status Class
      self.options.statusTime = 5000; // Here set your statusTime based on 'status'
      setTimeout( function() {
      classie.remove( self.el, statusClass );
      statusEl.draw(0);
      self._enable();
      }, self.options.statusTime );   
  }
```

To be able to have a different `statusTime` for each Button, what you could potentially do is set the `statusTime` (like I mentioned in the fiddle) based on a buttonId or a class etc.
you could have another if statement that does this.